# how to use redux-action package with requirejs

Tags: webpack, babeljs, redux, node-modules

I am new to latest-greatest stuff in JavaScript, especially modules.
Actually I am learning react with redux and TypeScript and also tried to use redux-actions package. However I cannot load this package with requirejs.

I suspect that it is not amd/umd compatible.
When I look at the node-modules for redux-actions there are 5 files. How should I convert them to be amd/umd and use it with requirejs? I tried do it with gulp with webpack but there are 5 files which contains internal require() invocations and I have no idea how to start

Comment: It is better to file an issue into [project home](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-actions) about this

Comment: Did you find any way to solve your problem. I see it was asked two months ago and I got the same issue now. If you solved your problem, please do share the result with us